# Will css text-transform: uppercase and capitalize work on any language without changing word meaning

Tags: css, translation

In our UI we want to support translation for over 100 languages. Base on our english UI, we have some `text-transform: uppercase` and `text-transform: capitalize` within the CSS. Mainly for visual tweak purpose.

We are now about to implement the translation layer and we are wondering if using `text-transform: uppercase` can be an error.

**Could the uppercasing change the meaning of a word in some maybe uncommon languages?**

We don't want the word `banana` to mean something lowercased which differs from `BANANA` in some languages.

Comment: It's not a survey but a real question. The fact is experience form other devs could help determine if the meaning of a word can be changed by uppercasing via CSS. Or if we can rely on this standard. It's not opinion related.

Comment: Some things that immediately spring to mind. 1) Changing "who" to "WHO" in English also alters the meaning, because WHO is an acronym. 2) In German, nouns are capitalised, so I wouldn't be surprised if you could make a German sentence which would have a different meaning when titlecased. (Can't think of any examples though.) So my answer is it's highly likely.

Answer (score 1):

`Uppercase` (all characters uppercase) shouldn't change the meaning of words, capitalization (only the first character of each word) though can change a name from common to proper in many languages. From my humble point of view, maybe this is a question for a linguistic, the first is safe and the later may me more problematic.

In case of doubt I wouldn't use them.